# Establishing relationships while aggregating more tables into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a problem I need to solve - I'm developing a data model for new application. I'm using code first .net core.

In my app user can create multiple new items, with every item having little different attributes. I need to 'aggregate' these items into one table so I can for example add commentaries on each item.

Therefore there is always 1:1 relationship between `Item1` and `AggItem` and `Item2` and `AggItem`.

Table `AggItem` does exactly that. There should be composite primary key consisting of

1. ItemId which is primary key in `Item1` or `Item2` tables
2. `ItemType` which is `string` that will distinguish between items

I've already tried a lot of things, but I can't really get this working. I really just wanna have the data model up and running at this point.

Any help appreciated!

Data in the `AggItem` table will look like this:

```
ID  ItemId  ItemType    Description
1   1       "item1"     "First item from table Item1"
2   2       "item1"     "Second item from table Item1"
3   1       "item2"     "First item from table Item2"
4   2       "item2"     "Second item from table Item2"
```

App Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<AggItem>().HasKey(table => new {
        table.ItemId,
        table.ItemType
    });
}
```

Domain class models:

```
public class Item1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UsedByCompany { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public int AggItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual AggItem AggItem { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Confidentiality { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public int AggItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual AggItem AggItem { get; set; }
}

public class AggItem
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }

    public virtual Comments {get; set;}
    public virtual Item1 item1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Item2 item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Item1 create method:

```
[BindProperty]
public Item1 Item1 { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    var aggItem = new AggItem
    {
        item1 = Item1,
        Description = Item1.Description,
        ItemType = "Item1",
        ItemId = Item1.Id
    };

    _context.Add(new Item1
    {
        Description = Item1.Description,
        AggItem = aggItem

    });

    _context.item1.Add(Item1);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use OO inheritance model. Item1, Item2 shoud inherit from BaseItem.
More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance